# Prism for WPF - How to send CancelEventArgs to viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, prism

How to send `CancelEventArgs` to the viewmodel on window close? I tried following way, but CloseWindow command method always receive `CancelEventArgs` argument as null. How to get `CancelEventArgs` to viewmodel in prism way?

```
<!-- View-->
    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}"  />
        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel

```
CloseWindowCommand =  DelegateCommand<CancelEventArgs>.FromAsyncHandler(CloseWindow);

public async Task CloseWindow(CancelEventArgs args)
{
   //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Prism's own `InvokeCommandAction` class:

```
xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
...
<interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
        <prism:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CloseWindowCommand}" />
    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
</interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The `InvokeCommandAction` class that is part of the Blend SDK doesn't support passing the `EventArgs` as a command parameter.