# Change SelectedItem within SelectionChanged-Event Command

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with the SelectedItem bound to a property in my ViewModel. A Command is executed on the SelectionChanged-Event:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCommand}"/>
         </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </DataGrid>
```

In `MyCommand` under certain circumstances I want to set the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to the value it was before the Selection was changed. But the selection highlighting in the DataGrid does not change nevertheless.

Is it possible to prevent ("`Handled = true;`") the SelectionChanged-Event in the attached Command?

Comment: you'd better go through the viewmodel SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem}"

Comment: "Is it possible to prevent..."? Not using the InvokeCommandAction class that is part of the Blend SDK but you could use Prism's InvokeCommandAction class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385864/prism-for-wpf-how-to-send-canceleventargs-to-viewmodel/42390256#42390256

Comment: @mm8 Thx, but I use the Blend SDK.

Comment: Then the answer to your question is no.

Comment: If you post your comment as answer, I can mark it as such.